# firebase storage protection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to know if there is a way to protect the files in the firebase storage from reading.

I am uploading html and css code for a project. However, the rules don't seem to limit the access to these resources. Anyone who obtains the link can read the code and it is still in constant change and I want to protect it while performing the modifications. Is there some rule that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> it is still in constant change and I want to protect it while
>   performing the modifications,

In general I suggest you to not modify rules on the live object, make yourself a test project and test the modified rules before applying them, also you could use the Simulator in the Rules Tab before taking them live.

The rules are the way you protect the storage, if someone accesses the url of one of your files but is not authorized, for example not logged in he should have no Access.

> the rules don't seem to limit the access

Thats exactly what they do, they check the Request and if any Security Rule doesnt fit then the read wont happen and the person wont get access to the file.

[Here is the API Reference with tons of use cases and commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/)